# Retrofit - how to ignore table name

Tags: android, api, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to get some items out of an API, which looks like this:

```
{ "picklist": [ 
{ "name": "Abkhazia", "id": "a0511000002gxF1AAI" },
{ "name": "Afghanistan", "id": "a0511000002gxF2AAI" },
{ "name": "Akrotiri and Dhekelia", "id": "a0511000002gxF3AAI" },
{ "name": "Albania", "id": "a0511000002gxF5AAI" },
{ "name": "Algeria", "id": "a0511000002gxF6AAI" },
{ "name": "American Samoa", "id": "a0511000002gxF7AAI" }
] }
```

I tried fetching it this way:

```
public interface MyAPI {
    @GET("/?country=true")
    Call<List<User>> getUsers();
}
```

But because the table has a name it throws an exception (at least I think that's why):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Add your User entity

Comment: check in postman with url and params. There must be some problem with either your url or server response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a custom response for this case:

```
public interface MyAPI {
    @GET("/?country=true")
    Call<APIResponse> getUsers();
}

class APIResponse {
    @JsonProperty("picklist") List<User> userList;
}
```

Where `@JsonProperty` is a [Jackson annotation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations). If you don't have this annotations you can always change the APIResponse to:

```
class APIResponse {
    List<User> picklist;
}
```